# Wpf Animating Opacity and Drag Moving Window at the Same Time Makes Window Stutter

Tags: wpf

I'm using this code to lower window's opacity when user moving it and after drag move is completed i'm incresing window's opacity to it's original value.

```
private void TopBar_Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
        {          
            if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
            {            
                var decreaseOpacityAnim = new DoubleAnimation(0.5, (Duration)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                this.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, decreaseOpacityAnim);
                this.DragMove();
                var increaseOpacityAnim = new DoubleAnimation(1, (Duration)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                this.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, increaseOpacityAnim);
            }

        }
```

The problem is when user started to move window and the time window's opacity decreasing, window moves stutter. When animation completed window starts moving without stuttering.

Is there anything i can do to fix this?

Comment: Which control corresponds to `TopBar_Grid_MouseDown` ? What `this.DragMove()` does?

Comment: "TopBar_Grid_MouseDown" is a grid and "this.DragMove()" moves the window => https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.windows.window.dragmove(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled `MouseMove` instead of `MouseDown`. And secondly, you are using both animations while dragging, hence this stutter. Below code works absolutely fine for me.

```
<Window ...>    
    <Grid Background="Yellow" MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove_1"/>    
</Window>
```

Code :

```
private bool animation_is_running = false;
private void Grid_MouseMove_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            if (!animation_is_running)
            {
                var decreaseOpacityAnim = new DoubleAnimation(0.5, (Duration)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                this.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, decreaseOpacityAnim);
                animation_is_running = true;
            }

            this.DragMove();
        }
        else
        {
            if (animation_is_running)
            {
                var increaseOpacityAnim = new DoubleAnimation(1, (Duration)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                this.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, increaseOpacityAnim);
                animation_is_running = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just tried your code but unfortunately it didn't change anything. Exactly same behaviour with my code. Window's moving is not smooth when opacity animation is running. When the animation finished you can move the window around very smooth. And i just noticed my "Intel Core i7"  cpu usage is jumping to ~%5-%7 when the animation is running. I'm sure something is not right here : S . By the way i don't know if it's important but Window's AllowTransparency is set to true and WindowStyle is None.

Comment: I tried changing animation's frame rate and i noticed if i decrease frame rate i get less stutter but animation doesn't look good. "Timeline.SetDesiredFrameRate(decreaseOpacityAnim, 2);"

Comment: @user2617750 see my updated code, it works perfectly fine smoothly.